# TSQL query optimization

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query where the predicate is determined at run time. Based on my current design the return time on the query is less than optimal. The query isn't complicated and I have verified that the indexes that are needed (using Tuning Adviser) are in place. I have proven to myself that the query could be faster if the predicate was hard-coded.

Below is the query I am having issues.

The following query takes several minutes to complete

```
declare
   @matchFN                   bit         = 1     -- match on first name
  ,@matchLN                   bit         = 1     -- match on last name

;with cteContact1 as (
  select distinct
     c.ContactID 
    ,ltrim(rtrim(FirstName)) FN
    ,ltrim(rtrim(LastName)) LN
  from 
    dbo.contact c 
  left outer join
    dbo.ContactCertification cc on c.ContactID = cc.ContactID   
)
,cteContact2 as (
  select 
     c.ContactID 
    ,ltrim(rtrim(FirstName)) FN
    ,ltrim(rtrim(LastName)) LN
  from 
    dbo.contact c  
  left outer join
    dbo.ContactCertification cc on c.ContactID = cc.ContactID   
)
select distinct
   *
from
  cteContact1 c1
join
  cteContact2 c2 on 
    c1.FN = case when @matchFN = 1 then c2.FN else c1.FN end
    and
    c1.LN = case when @matchLN = 1 then c2.LN else c1.LN end
```

However, if I change the the final query to the following the query completes in under 5 seconds.

```
select distinct
   *
from
  cteContact1 c1
join      
  cteContact2 c2 on c1.FN = c2.FN  and c1.LN = c2.LN
```

Ultimately, both queries should boil down to the same thing so why the dramatic difference in performance?

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans for each variant of the query?

Comment: Yes, the bulk of the work in the 'fast' version is in a Merge Join (Inner Join) - 85%.  The bulk of the work in the slow version is in  Nested Loops (Inner Join) - 97%.  I would have thought that both queries should result in the same query plan when matchFN and matchLN = 1.

Comment: But the query optimizer is not aware of the values of matchFN and matchLN so the query optimizer is not aware it is the same query.   Try for yourself to change those values and see if the query plan changes.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Ok, so my solution is to use dynamic sql and build the query based on predicate that are selected at run time.  This has solved my performance issue.

Comment: Your second query returns a lot less records than the first.  The first one will duplicate your records since you are setting c1.FN and c1.LN to themselves if "@matchFN" and "@matchLN" aren't 1.  Since the 2nd table returns much less records as a result of the narrower join criteria, it will run much faster